# dangers to user css

Tags: css

Are there any dangers or security risks in allowing user css?

Sorry for unspecific question. Possible implementation: having a textarea for users to input custom css, and then taking that css and putting it into a style element: `<style type="text/css"></style>` with js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are many potential XSS attacks, mostly through putting JavaScript in urls for background-image and whatnot. Search for "style" in the [XSS Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) for some examples.

There is also the potential that the user CSS could break your site, for example making the navigation menu 0x0 pixels or moving it offscreen to -1000, -1000. Or the CSS itself could reference images from other sites, which you can't guarantee will continue to stay up.

Comment: To be fair, these are only issues if users are allowed to change css in a manner that is available to other users, or if Malicious Mandy figures out a way to get users to use her malicious CSS. If this is a purely-client-side thing, they could break their own experience of the site, but meh.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you implement that functionality. If you provide a form that allows people to select their own CSS values, then there's an inherent risk of dirty input.

Comment: Answer made under the assumption that "user css" means something like allowing users to change CSS settings in a profile page.

Answer (score 1):

### All user input is dirty

What if they write some CSS that hides or obscures something like a login?

There are multiple issues as well, there is a CSS history hack, several XSS vulnerabilities related to url's, and probably more that haven't been thought of.

**Always sanitize user input before displaying it on a page.**

Answer (score 1):

If the only user affected by the CSS is the user that provided the CSS, then there's not much of a risk. Any XSS vulnerability could only affect the user.

Some browsers allow users to use custom CSS anyway, or ignore it altogether, so I wouldn't consider it a problem.