# Is there a security threat if I enable a user to add CSS?

Tags: security, css

Is it not secure to enable user to add his own rules of CSS to his personal page, in (for example) a social website ?

Comment: Yes? The question is, what is the threat, and how does it fit into your overall strategy for dealing with intrusions.

Comment: Belongs on Stackoverflow, since there's nothing subjective about it (it's either secure or not, regardless of whether "secure" can be defined/interpreted in different ways).

Comment: If "secure" is subjective, a question wether something is secure is also subjective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dangers to user css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380123/dangers-to-user-css)

Answer (score 12):

It is **not secure**. There are multiple ways to embed JavaScript in CSS such that it gets executed by at least some browsers. Google "XSS CSS" and look through the top hits.

Don't do this unless you're willing to do hardcore sanitization of the CSS, and to clean up the mess when your sanitization is inevitably bypassed and your users' cookies are compromised.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing them to enter the CSS as free-form text (or upload a file) could lead to security problems. It might be safer to give them a Control Panel that lets them customize the look and feel (with limiations of course, it might be impossible to build a form that lets them customize EVERYthing), and implement the customization via CSS, while storing their settings as values in a structured set of database tables.

Comment: One consideration is the difference between secure in the sense that you could block XSS attacks, and secure in the sense that a naughty person could use CSS to create a phishing page - using background-images to make a page look like a user's login page for example.

Comment: @Blowski: Good point. Blocking against a misleading background image would be difficult. Easiest way would be to limit users to a large set of pre-chosen images, OR if they are allowed to upload images then the images would have to be manually approved by staff.

Answer (score 2):

I think [somebody answered this question before](http://myspace.com/).

History lesson: myspace allowed custom CSS and scripts. For those of you not hanging around on the web in 2003 or so, this was a major security threat. Later on, the mass of user generated CSS which had been a selling point became a major detriment to the platform as many changes and improvements could not be made as they effectively had created a public API for their CSS hooks.

So it is a really, really bad idea to let users do CSS.

Comment: I thought maybe Myspace had a big CSS XSS exploit or something -- I found out that they've had XSS attacks (like every major website) and that they also allow custom user CSS. Nothing that one caused the other though, so I dunno, maybe it is the wrong URL.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to provide a bit more context. But no, I didn't paste the wrong URL.

Comment: @Wyatt Barnett: It's a good lesson, do you have any links to articles that discuss the MySpace problems in particular?

Comment: yes please give us references to myspace.com problem as i want to know what was exactly the problem to avoid it

Comment: Most of the "myspace is dead" articles you see recently allude to some of this problem, but there isn't a cannonical reference. To some extent it was a huge underlying issue plaguing myspace for most of it's existence and it was pretty much an unsolvable problem once that cat got out of the bag. I think twitter does a pretty good job of letting one customize their page without opening the door to horrible exploits and that much fuglyness.